# Assigning element attribute to an other element's innerhtml. Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm working on a website, and the pictures page I'm trying to create has 1 big picture, with smaller thumbnails underneath. I have a javascript function in the head:

`function loadThumbnail(divID){
    document.getElementById("mainPicture").src = document.getElementById(divID).src;
    document.getElementById("mainPicture").alt = document.getElementById(divId).alt;
    document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = document.getElementById(divId).alt;
}`

The parameter divID is a misleading title, it's actually the ID of the img element that holds the thumbnail. The function is called whenever the user clicks a thumbnail. The .src bit works, but I can't get the function to change the caption to the picture. Any idea why?

Edit: Here's the HTML

```
<img id="mainPicture" src="images/food/chickenAndCheeseFries1.png" width="420" height="313" alt="Chicken Tenders and Cheese Fries">

<p id="caption">Chicken tenders and cheese fries</p>

<div onClick="loadThumbnail('t1')" id="thumbnail1" class="thumbnail">
                                <div id="thumbnailPic1" class="thumbnailPic">
                                    <img id="t1" src="images/food/buffaloAndHotWings1.png" width="105" height="80" alt="Sweet Chilly and Buffalo Wings">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.getAttribute("alt")` instead of `.alt`?

Comment: I just tried now, no luck

Comment: At the first line you're using `divID` and at the other you're using `divId` which is `undefined` thus resulting in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the divID variable is used consistently, including the case.  It looks like you typoed and used "divId", which won't work.  Try it like this, "divID", in all cases.

```js
function loadThumbnail(divID) {
  document.getElementById("mainPicture").src = document.getElementById(divID).src;
  document.getElementById("mainPicture").alt = document.getElementById(divID).alt;
  document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = document.getElementById(divID).alt;
}
```

Case matters!  `divID != divId`

Comment: That's exactly it! Boy, do I feel a bit stupid. Can't believe that flew over of my head. Perhaps I should switch to a naming convention less prone to goofs like this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: It happens to everybody.  Now you know to look for it.  It may sound a little lazy, but careful use of copy/paste can avoid this problem if you have names that give you problems.